# Using monad transformers change expression result

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, monad-transformers

I found a behavior of monad transformers that is not at all intuitive for me.

Taking following data as an example:

```scala
type F[X] = OptionT[Either[String, *], X]

val success: F[Int] = 1.pure[F]

val empty: F[Int] = ().raiseError[F, Int]

val failed = "Boom!".raiseError[Either[String, *], Int].liftTo[F]
```

And then executing a line:

```scala
(success, empty, failed).tupled.value // Right(None)
```

We still get a `Right`, but I'd expect to see `Left("Boom!")` instead, as `Either` is an outermost effect. But when order is slightly modified:

```scala
(success, failed, empty).tupled.value // Left(Boom!)
```

This yields an expected value. Another thing is when we take values out of monad transformers before `tupled` and apply them in initial order:

```scala
(success.value, empty.value, failed.value).tupled // Left(Boom!)
```

We get a value that seems to me intuitive, but is not consistent with a result from the first example.

Does anyone know why monad transformers behave in this way? I simply considered monad tranformers a convenient way of working with stacked monads, but this seems to add more depth, as whether I use them or not it might actually yield a different value.

Comment: Transformers form their own different `Monads` with their own behaviors, distinct to the unwrapped versions. The point of `OptionT` is that if the value inside of it is an `F[None]` then `flatMap` would return another `F[None]` just like `flatMap` on `None` returns a `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me point to things that contribute to that behavior:

- monad transformer provides a data type, that is “focusing” on monad inside, in a way allowing programmer to ignore the handling/plumbing related with “external” data type, yet combining the capabilities of both
- `.tupled` is simply a syntax sugar over chained `.ap`/`.zip` calls, which in turn, have to be consistent with `.flatMap`

Then, what happens in particular cases, becomes way more obvious if we write it as a sequence of `flatMap`s:

- `(success, empty, failed).tupled.value // Right(None)` - `empty` short-circuits evaluation on whole stack (whole point of using `OptionT`!), so `failed` is not executed/taken into consideration
- `(success, failed, empty).tupled.value // Left(Boom!)` - this time it’s `failed`, which short-circuits evaluation, on external type though
- `(success.value, empty.value, failed.value).tupled // Left(Boom!)` - here all values are `Either` values, so it’s `failed`, which makes expression to “fail”

This particular behavior - one effect in a way “overriding” or adding new semantic to the other, because of using transformers, is generally consider something to be careful with, because it shows how important order of stacking becomes - I learned about it on example of `Writer[T]` position in stack, when used for logging - it has to be in right position to not forget logs to be written in presence of e.g. error.

Below is an example of such behavior:

```scala
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._
import cats.mtl._
import cats.mtl.syntax.all._
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global

def print[A: Show](value: A): IO[Unit] = IO { println(value.show) }

type Foo[A] = WriterT[EitherT[IO, String, _], List[String], A]

def runFoo[A: Show](value: Foo[A]): Unit = {
  value.run.value.flatMap(print).unsafeRunSync()
}

type Bar[A] = EitherT[WriterT[IO, List[String], _], String, A]

def runBar[A: Show](value: Bar[A]): Unit = {
  value.value.run.flatMap(print).unsafeRunSync()
}

def doSucceed[F[_]: Monad](
    value: Int
)(using t: Tell[F, List[String]]): F[Int] = {
  for {
    _ <- t.tell(s"Got value ${value}" :: Nil)
    newValue = value + 1
    _ <- t.tell(s"computed: ${newValue}" :: Nil)
  } yield newValue
}

def doFail[F[_]](
    value: Int
)(using t: Tell[F, List[String]], err: MonadError[F, String]): F[Int] = {
  for {
    _ <- t.tell(s"Got value ${value}" :: Nil)
    _ <- "Boo".raiseError[F, Int]
  } yield value
}

runFoo(doSucceed[Foo](42)) // prints Right((List(Got value 42, computed: 43),43))
runBar(doSucceed[Bar](42)) // prints (List(Got value 42, computed: 43),Right(43))

runFoo(doFail[Foo](42)) // prints Left(Boo)
runBar(doFail[Bar](42)) // prints (List(Got value 42),Left(Boo))
```